# QueryString converted to URL-Encode using NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, urlencode

I am passing an encrypted URL string:

**Default.aspx?S3tLlnIKKzE%3d**

I want to pass that URL string back into the ASPX page in a variable.

```
protected string qs = string.Empty;

NameValueCollection qscollstring = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
qs = qscollstring[0];
```

Which return :  S3tLlnIKKzE=

The value in qscollstring[0] is correct: S3tLlnIKKzE%3d

I understand the problem is URL-Encoding, but I cannot find a way to keep the string as is.

It seems that assigning the value from qscollstring[0] is: **S3tLlnIKKzE%3d**
to string changes the value : **S3tLlnIKKzE=**

I need to to stay: **S3tLlnIKKzE%3d**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method to encode the string.

```
 qs =HttpUtility.UrlEncode(qscollstring[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pull the value from the Uri of the current URL without having to Encode the value.

Sample:

```
 Uri u = new Uri("http://localhost.com/default.aspx?S3tLlnIKKzE%3d");
 string q = u.Query;
```

And part of your page:

```
 string q = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Url.Query) && Request.Url.Query.Length > 1 ? Request.Url.Query.Substring(1) : Request.Url.Query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like me if you are searching for the `reverse` .. use

```
qs =HttpUtility.UrlDecode("S3tLlnIKKzE%3d");
```

to get back **S3tLlnIKKzE=**